# Create patch based on email and date range in git

Tags: git, repository, diff, patch, git-diff

1) Assumptions (fake data):

**git log**

```
commit 12ddf89asdfash323jhkfhsadfyas23ifhafdf
Author: Karol Dok <Karol.Dok@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 18:06:44 2014 +0200
TTTT_6222 Coment5.

commit asdf7623rkjadf98723rfaefdsas7d6fa9sass
Author: Tom Tyt <Tom.Tyt@gmail.com>
Date:   Feb Feb 26 7:06:44 2014 +0200
TTTT_4532 Coment4.

commit bs90s7dfgsdfgsfd8g7sd0fg7sd0f98g7sdfgs
Author: Karol Dok <Karol.Dok@gmail.com>
Date:   Wen Feb 10 9:16:44 2014 +0200
TTTT_4532 Coment3.
```

2) Generate patch based on date range 01.02.14-28.02.14 made by "Karol.Dok@gmail.com"

**git diff --email='Karol.Dok@gmail.com' --daterange='01.02.14-28.02.14' > patchTest.patch**

Answer (score 1):

Generate diff with author and date (start-end) filter:

```
git log --since "MAY 1 2017" --until "MAY 31 2017" -p --author="Jack" > diffJackMay.patch
```